# Layout: "2 columns into max-width+centered wrapper" with stretching option

Tags: css, flexbox

I'm trying to achieve a variation of a two columns layout, into a basic max-width + centered wrapper (on mobile the second column would stack under the first one).
The trick is that on bigger screen I would like the second column to stretch all the way to the right side of the screen.

I achieved it, using *flexbox* and `calc()` and it falls back to the regular layout if `calc()` is not supported:

Sass :

```
$content-max-width: 500px;
$horiz-padding: 50px;
$minvw: $content-max-width + $horiz-padding * 2;
/* decorations */
body {  
  margin: 0;
  * { box-sizing: border-box; }
  .wrapper {
    & > * {
      border: solid 2px #666;
      min-height: 80vh;
    }
    .content {
      box-shadow: 0 3px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, .25)
    }
    .main {
      min-height: 50vh;
      background-color: #bbffbb;
    }
    .expanded {
      background-color: #ffbbbb;
      > * {
        background-color: #ffffbb;
        height: 100%;
      }
    }
  }
}
/* mobile first */
.wrapper {  
  padding: 0 $horiz-padding;
  .content {
    max-width: $content-max-width;
    margin: 0 auto;
  }
}
/* large screen */
@media (min-width: $minvw) {
  .wrapper {
    display: flex;
    padding-right: calc(0px);
    .content {
      flex-grow: 1;
      display: flex;
      max-width: calc(99999px);      
      margin: 0 0 0 calc( (100vw - #{$content-max-width} - #{$horiz-padding}*2) * .5);
    }
  }
  .main {
    flex-basis: $content-max-width * .5;
  }
  .expanded {
    flex-grow: 1;
    > * {
      width: $content-max-width *.5;
    }
  }
}
```

And HTML markup :

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="content">
    <div class="main">main...</div>
    <div class="expanded">
      <div>expanded...</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

In action : https://jsfiddle.net/leonsaysHi/uu6gg7uj/

I was wondering if there is any solution to achieve this without relying on `calc()` as it is not yet widely supported.

Thanks a lot.

**Edit:** you can change the value of $content-max-width to see what I mean.

**2nd edit:** here is an image showing what I am trying to achieve :
[image]

Comment: Please include your code in the question itself. Also, answers on this site are intended to provide clear solutions to coding problems. You're asking for general feedback so your question is likely to be closed. If you want your code reviewed, consider this Stack site: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Edited, am I good?

Comment: Since CSS Calc has better browser support than Flexbox, no reason to find a solution without it

Comment: Btw, your `max-width: calc(99999px);` syntax is invalid. Calc need minimum of 2 values

Comment: Thanks a lot @LGSon

Answer (score 0):

The behavior you are seeking are all out of the box with Bootstrap or Foundation. you can easily create responsive columns in either framework using their column classes.

```
<div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">First Column</div>
<div class="col-md-9 col-sm-9 col-xs-12">Second Column</div>
```

*This is only example markup - you will need to use the documentation to fully implement your desired functionality.

Changing the order of these divs in your code will determine which is displayed on the left / top.

[W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/) has a lot of helpful docs on bootstrap

Comment: Thanks, but maybe I was not clear, I want it to behave like a centered two column layout, except the second column stretches all the way to the right side of the screen. So it would be [auto margin] [1st column] [stretched 2nd column] [no-margin] ... but the 1st column should be the same size at it would be if there were an auto margin on the right side.

Comment: You could still do that with bootstrap or foundation, but you would have to make your own classes to override the bootstrap margins. the column sizes I used were just for example. Unless I am not understanding your question?

Comment: Hi, none of the grid library I know of would do the work because they all setup fluid columns whereas in what I am trying to achieve one of the column is fixed, the other fluid. I have edit my question with a picture to show you. Thanks.